# How to install VS Code in Alpine Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, alpine-linux

I have an operating environment that is Alpine linux only and I need to install VS Code. How can VS Code be run on Alpine Linux?

Comment: I think it may be very difficult to accomplish. It is not officially supported on Alpine, AFAIK. Since Visual Studio code is only compatible with gibc, and not with Alpine's musl libc, it requires patching Alpine with glibc (not a difficult procedure); then you have to figure out the exact apk packages needed (there are quite a lot: `ldd code | wc -l` result is 100), and hope that non of them is missing from Alpine (otherwise these packages need to build from source); then, run it and hope it works... There's an open 2016 code segfault report on Alpine: https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/6588

Comment: Or, run it from a debian docker...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.19.0-alpine
RUN set -x \
    && sed -i 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/g' /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --no-cache add alpine-sdk bash libstdc++ libc6-compat \
    && npm config set python python3 
RUN git clone --recursive https://github.com/cdr/code-server.git
RUN cd code-server
RUN yarn global add code-server

ENV PASSWORD=changeme
ENTRYPOINT code-server --bind-addr 0:8443
```

Commands:

```
docker build . -t vscode
docker run -d -e PASSWORD=111111 -p8443:8443 vscode:latest
http://hostname:8443
```

Comment: Finally, the answer after 3.5 years. Thank you JohnTang!

Comment: in case you want to do this from inside WSL Alpine you can not because you are already in docker ... thus do the above from the command line :)

Comment: @ChefGladiator WSL can use the host machine's docker socket if you bind it to a TCP port in windows. Then you can run docker in WSL to launch containers on the host Docker for Windows VM.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download it in Flatpak repos, it will run natively in a Gnome SDK environment.
2. Use a self-hosted environment such as Theia (https://www.theia-ide.org/index.html) or coder-editor (https://coder.com/). I've never tried them, I use the Flatpak one, but they seem interesting (you can "build" your osn editor in a Node environment).

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for necrobump, but as what Marco suggested, coder.com has moved to [github](https://github.com/cdr)

the software, [code-server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server) is quite litterally VSCode, as a web application, I have been using this for about half a year and it is quite well developed, Alpine support is still spotty but i recall getting a few releases to function well a while back when i ran Alpine as my main.